# How to send messages to specific channels

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

How to send messages to specific channels:

```py
@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = ctx.author
    admin_role = get(guild.roles, name="admin")
    manager_role = get(guild.roles, name="manager")
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role : nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        user : nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        admin_role : nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        manager_role : nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'ticket-{user.name}', overwrites=overwrites)
    ch = guild.get_channel(f"{channel.id}")
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="**repots!**", description=f"<@{user.id}>message", color=0x00ff40)
    mesg = await ch.send(embed=embed)
```

Channel is created, but messages are not shown on the created channel.

**Error message:**

```py
mesg = await ch.message.send(embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Comment: your problem here is ch is a none type object meaning your ch = None that means when you are fetching the channel it shows channel not found so check your channel ID also i would use ch=discord.utils.get(CTX.message.guild, name="ticket")

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a message to a channel, you just have to use the channel object with `.send(message content)`. You don't need `.message`. You also don't have to use `get_channel` because you already store the created channel object in the variable `channel`.

Remove:

```py
ch = guild.get_channel(f"{channel.id}")
```

Change:

```py
mesg = await ch.message.send(embed=embed)
```

To:

```py
mesg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
```